# How do I install IIS on Windows XP without the XP Install disk?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I need to test my website and on IIS, but I dont have my original Windows XP CD to install Windows components.  Is there another way to install it or can someone suggest alternative methods for my purpose.

Comment: Well, if you just need "a" webserver you could install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) which is freely downloadable.

Answer (score 1):

With [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx)